# Sample Function in R returning same value over and over

Tags: r, simulation, sample

I am trying to simulate rolling three dice and taking their sum but for some reason this code is returning 11 over and over.

```
sample(3:18 ,1, prob = c(1/216, 3/216, 6/216, 10/216, 15/216, 21/216, 25/216, 27/216, 27/216, 25/216, 21/216, 15/216, 10/216, 6/216, 3/216, 1/216))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it only returns 11

Comment: With that said I find `sum(sample(1:6, 3, replace = TRUE))` to be a more intuitive way to simulate what you want.

Comment: So it is not a problem with the code. I even changed it to your code and its returning 8 every time now. What would cause R Studio to return the same number over and over with that code? I did not use set.seed and my environment is cleared.

Comment: Are you using set.seed somewhere

Answer (score 0):

When I rerun your code 100 times, I get a variety of results. In other words, your code doesn't seem to produce the issue you describe.

```r
replicate(n = 100,
          expr = {
            sample_probs <- c(1/216, 3/216, 6/216, 10/216,
                              15/216, 21/216, 25/216, 27/216,
                              27/216, 25/216, 21/216, 15/216,
                              10/216, 6/216, 3/216, 1/216)
            
            sample(3:18, size = 1,
                   prob = sample_probs)
          })
#>   [1] 12 11 11 11  8  8 11  9 10 15  8 16  9 16 14 15  9 12  8 11 12 13 16  8 12
#>  [26] 11  5 11 14 16 11  7 11 15  8 11  9  5  6  6 12  8  8  7 10  5 10 14  8 10
#>  [51] 10 10 13  6 16  9  9 10 10 14 11  7 16 12 10 13  8 11 11  9 11  8 13  8 11
#>  [76]  4 12  9 13 13 11  8  6  8 14  9 15 12  8  7  6 11 10 11  4  9 10  9 14 12
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Okay, so I guess the problem is not the code?? because it keeps returning the same number over and over again when i run it. i cleared my environment so I have no idea what could be causing this

Comment: It isn't always 11. But its just seems like its randomly picking one number and returning it over and over. Then I tweak something and it returns a different number over and over.

Comment: Can you update your reprex using the `reprex` package? It'd be helpful to see *all* the code you're running and the output. Otherwise, it's not clear that there's an actual problem and you're not just getting unlucky with legitimate random numbers: https://imgur.com/gallery/uR4WuQ0